# to-infinitive+infinitive+pronoun (e.g., to Help Keep You)?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I found the sentence of "to Help Keep You Safe and Secure" in a text and got confused. If I were to write it, I would use keep after pronoun, as "to Help You Keep Safe and Secure". Can anyone explain why the first format "to verb+verb+pronoun" is correct?

Thanks

Comment: To me, there is a slight difference in meaning. "To Help Keep You Safe and Secure" implies that the measures which are being adopted aim to protect you. The second instance suggests that you get some advice with regard to what you can do in order to keep safe and secure.

Comment: Different structure, but both are grammatical, and many will not note any difference (though discerning speakers may agree with @Nico).

Comment: @JohnLawler I was not questioning the grammatical nature of both at all.

Comment: I meant they may agree with you about the meaning difference.

Comment: @Greybeard: No, it is different. The asker is not concerned about *help keep* v. *help to keep* but rather *help keep you* v. *help you keep*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks - I've removed it

Comment: The answer to the frame question is that "to + infinitive + infinitive" is not, in general, grammatical. It is a property of the word _help_ (like _dare_, and in some dialects _go_) that it may be followed by a bare infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is worthwhile to understand that

(a) “to help keep you secure” is a closely synonymous with “to assist your security”

(b) “to help you keep secure” is a closely synonymous with “to assist you in keeping yourself secure.”

> I found the sentence: "to help keep you safe and secure "

That is not a sentence… You need to add to it:

“*We have fitted stronger locks to the door* to help keep you safe and secure

In full, this is

1. “We have fitted stronger locks to the door **in order** to help keep you safe and secure.

In this, (i) **keep** is a bare infinitive and (ii) “you” is the object of “keep” and (iii) “safe and secure” is a compound adjective and the complement of “keep.”

The meaning thus emphasises that our fitting the locks is **keeping you** safe and secure.

Your alternative thus becomes

1. “We have fitted stronger locks to the door **in order** to help you keep safe and secure"

In this, **keep** is a bare infinitive and “you” is the object of “**help**” and “**safe and secure**” is a compound adjective and the complement of “keep.”

The meaning thus emphasises that our fitting the locks is **helping  you** to be safe and secure.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: What is the subject of *keep*?

> (1) to help [ ___ keep you safe and secure ]
>
> (2) to help you  [ ___ keep safe and secure ]

In the first it is not clear what the subject of *keep* is without more context or the addition of some further element. In two, the understood subject is *you*. Compare:

> (3) to help you [ ___ keep **yourself** safe and secure ]

With the reflexive pronoun it is clear that only the interpretation with *you* as subject of *keep* is possible.

When *help* has an object and a bare infinitival complement, it's understood that the subject of that bare infinitival is same as the object of *help*.

(1) is correct in situations where someone else is keeping you safe and secure, (2) where you are keeping yourself safe and secure. In (1) someone else is helped, in (2) you are helped.